# window.onload Javascript, with functions that receives parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var car = document.getElementById("Carros").value;
    window.onload = ChangeValue(car);

    function ChangeValue(str)
    {   
       ....
    }
```

See that `ChangeValue(str)` receives a parameter, how may I make it start in the pageLoad?
using javascript ! The parameter I pass is a `<select id="" onChange="ChangeValue(this.value)">`

Comment: this is very unusual.  You are setting the `onLoad event` on the `window` to a `function` that takes a `parameter` but you are trying to pull the `parameter` from the page that hasn't loaded yet... Use Jeffman's solution it is much more appropriate.

Comment: @abc123 I was wrong I know it... I just wanted to know the right way, thank you!

Comment: The question doesnt make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
    var car = document.getElementById("Carros").value;
    ChangeValue(car);
}
```

Comment: I didnt accepted it yet, beucase it said i Had to wait 11minuts ;P  
Does it increasce performance aswell, or just to clean my code?

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake and put the code back the way it was.